# Calculate the number of users per month, grouped by the first month, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to count the number of users for each month, grouping this by month of first visit.
There is a table containing data: id - user number, FirstVisit - date of the first visit, LastVisit - date of the last visit.

| id | FirstVisit | LastVisit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03.02.2021 | 10.10.2021 |
| 2 | 10.02.2021 | 12.12.2021 |
| 3 | 15.01.2021 | 01.02.2022 |
| 4 | 14.05.2021 | 04.03.2022 |
| 5 | 12.05.2021 | 15.05.2021 |
| 1 | 03.02.2021 | 10.10.2021 |
| 3 | 15.01.2021 | 01.02.2022 |

As a result, I need to create a dataframe:

| FirstVisit | Month | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01 | 2021.01 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.02 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.03 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.04 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.05 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.06 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.07 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.08 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.09 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.10 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.11 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2021.12 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2022.01 | 1 |
| 2021.01 | 2022.02 | 1 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.02 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.03 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.04 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.05 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.06 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.07 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.08 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.09 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.10 | 2 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.11 | 1 |
| 2021.02 | 2021.12 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.05 | 2 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.06 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.07 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.08 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.09 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.10 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.11 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2021.12 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2022.01 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2022.02 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | 2022.03 | 1 |

I created a function to count the number of users for each month:

```
fun = lambda m:np.where((visit.FirstVisit <=m) & (visit.LastVisit >=m),visit.inn,0)
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(visit.FirstVisit.min(),visit.LastVisit.max(), freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m'),columns=['Month'])
df['cnt']=df.Month.map(lambda x:np.count_nonzero(np.unique(fun(x))))
```

But I can't add grouping by the FirstVisit field.

Created an approximate loop as I see the result, but still not correct yet

```
for i in (pd.date_range(visit.FirstVisit.min(),visit.FirstVisit.max(),freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m')):

for m in (pd.date_range(visit.FirstVisit.min(),visit.LastVisit.max(),freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m')):

    if (pd.to_datetime(visit.FirstVisit, format ='%Y-%m')==i) & (visit.FirstVisit<=m) & (visit.LastVisit >= m) :

        df1=df1.append({'FirstVisit': i,'Months': m,'cnt': df1.Month.map(lambda x:np.count_nonzero(np.unique(fun(x))))})
```

Comment: Please provide your data as text, not images.

Comment: Please provide your data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

I never used pandas before, so maybe this can be written more concisely. But it seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def to_month(s):
    d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m.%Y')
    d = d.date()
    d = d.replace(day=1)
    return d

def inc_month(d):
    year = d.year
    month = d.month
    if d.month == 12:
        year += 1
        month = 1
    else:
        month += 1
    return d.replace(year=year, month=month)


data = """
1   03.02.2021  10.10.2021
2   10.02.2021  12.12.2021
3   15.01.2021  01.02.2022
4   14.05.2021  04.03.2022
5   12.05.2021  15.05.2021
"""

records = [row.split() for row in data.split('\n') if row.strip()]
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['id', 'first_visit', 'last_visit'])

data_df[['first_visit', 'last_visit']] = data_df[['first_visit', 'last_visit']].applymap(to_month)

records = []
for i in range(len(data_df)) :
    first_visit = data_df.loc[i, 'first_visit']
    last_visit = data_df.loc[i, 'last_visit']
    val = first_visit
    while val <= last_visit:
        records.append((first_visit, val))
        val = inc_month(val)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['first_visit', 'month'])

df = df.groupby(['first_visit', 'month']).size().reset_index(name='count')

print(df)
```

Prints this:

```
   first_visit       month  count
0   2021-01-01  2021-01-01      1
1   2021-01-01  2021-02-01      1
2   2021-01-01  2021-03-01      1
3   2021-01-01  2021-04-01      1
4   2021-01-01  2021-05-01      1
5   2021-01-01  2021-06-01      1
6   2021-01-01  2021-07-01      1
7   2021-01-01  2021-08-01      1
8   2021-01-01  2021-09-01      1
9   2021-01-01  2021-10-01      1
10  2021-01-01  2021-11-01      1
11  2021-01-01  2021-12-01      1
12  2021-01-01  2022-01-01      1
13  2021-01-01  2022-02-01      1
14  2021-02-01  2021-02-01      2
15  2021-02-01  2021-03-01      2
16  2021-02-01  2021-04-01      2
17  2021-02-01  2021-05-01      2
18  2021-02-01  2021-06-01      2
19  2021-02-01  2021-07-01      2
20  2021-02-01  2021-08-01      2
21  2021-02-01  2021-09-01      2
22  2021-02-01  2021-10-01      2
23  2021-02-01  2021-11-01      1
24  2021-02-01  2021-12-01      1
25  2021-05-01  2021-05-01      2
26  2021-05-01  2021-06-01      1
27  2021-05-01  2021-07-01      1
28  2021-05-01  2021-08-01      1
29  2021-05-01  2021-09-01      1
30  2021-05-01  2021-10-01      1
31  2021-05-01  2021-11-01      1
32  2021-05-01  2021-12-01      1
33  2021-05-01  2022-01-01      1
34  2021-05-01  2022-02-01      1
35  2021-05-01  2022-03-01      1
```

Comment: When i write the loop code i get an error:  ---> return d.replace(year=year, month=month) . Value Error: day is out of range for month. Although when I try write the code line by line there are no errors. Can you suggest what it is?